# how to get the top left coordinates of the screen with javascript on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a `<div>` element with `position: absolute` and z-index something big. I would like to cover the entire screen with this div with javascript.
This is what I do and it works:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.top = 0;
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.left = 0;
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.width = '100%';
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.height = '100%';
```

However, when I scroll down with long webpages, this code displays my div at the top of the page, so the div renders above the region I currently view. 
How can I change the top and left values so that my div always covers the active field I am viewing?

I work on firefox 3.6.*.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to `position: fixed`.

Note that this won't work in IE6.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem. However, I would also like to learn a way to get the top and left values for the region relative to the entire page.

Comment: `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

Comment: suppose the height of the website I am viewing is 6000px and my browser height is 800px. When I scroll down to the very bottom of the page, the left-top coordinate of my viewing area will roughly be (0, 5200). I would like to know how I can get that height value at any part of the page.

Comment: You're looking for `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.